# graphs where distance between every two vertices is $\geq$2.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Are there any class of graphs where distance between every two vertices is $\geq$2. 
I was wondering about the existence of such graphs. Because for counter examples I have Paths $P_n$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  It seems only graphs with no edges fit your description.  As soon as we add an edge, we have two vertices of distance $1$ from each other.

Comment: If you define distance as the minimal length of a path between two vertices (and $\infty$ if no such path exists) then the answer is that only a graph without edges has this property. If there is any path between two vertices then someone is a neighbor of someone else.

Comment: You are absolutely right.... I had a slight doubt if it ever can happen, but now its cleared. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take this off the "unanswered" list:

The only graphs that fit your description are empty.  If $x y \in E$ is an edge, then $d(x,y) = 1$.